# HTTP Error 401 from yahoo weather api

Tags: java, yahoo-weather-api

Everything was working fine and then one day this happens:

> java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=946738&u=c

I took the api from [here](https://www.hightail.com/download/UlRUS3hlUzc1UjV3SGNUQw), and it was working just fine until 4 days ago, when `error 401` knocked my door! Why?

Comment: 401 means that your request is not authorized. Are you providing the required credentials to autheticate your request

Comment: https://github.com/eclipse/smarthome/issues/1273, Yahoo requires OAuth1 authentication for their weather api.